# I can't access web server outside of network

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I am trying to create an ubuntu web server. I have setup my domain name and port-forwarding on port 80 along with my hosts file. I can ping my domain name and i get a response from my public IP. I can also access the website within the network with either the domain name or internal IP. When i try to access the domain name from outside of the network it will not load. Ubuntu firewall is disabled by default and i setup my internal IP as static. I am using google domains and i have setup a "custom resource records" with an @ type A and my public IP. I am new to these types of things so this is an exercise in order to increase my knowledge. I just don't know why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming this isn't a question about managing information technology systems in a business environment (http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)? In that case I strongly suspect you're the victim of CGNAT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

Comment: Am I out of luck then :(?

Comment: Not at all. Invest in a vps or cloud vm. It doesn’t have to cost a lot more per month than the power for running an always-on server would. Look at the likes of Linode, Digital Ocean, AWS or Azure and compare their offerings.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate the help!